# How can I turn off keyboard features in react-beautiful-dnd?

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using react-beautiful-dnd and I want to turn off the keyboard features. If such a thing is not possible, I want to assign it to different keys. I found closed topics about this but no code examples. How can I turn off keyboard features?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

In cases where I needed to use the keyboard, I removed the drag feature in this way and it worked for me.

https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/draggable.md#interactive-child-elements-within-a-draggable-

A link that might be useful

Comment: Please *do not* share images of code, post the actual text content to improve SEO and to make it easier for other developers to copy/paste your code.